# C recursive function - Calling function in main displays incorrect values

Tags: c, function, recursion, sum

Right so, I have to write a recursive function that takes two values and calaculates the sum of all the numbers between the two values the user entered.

For example if a user were to put in the range of 4 as the first value and 7 as the second number it should print out the sum as 22. As 4+5+6=7 = 22.

So far I have written this code that sort of works but gives the wrong output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum( int x, int max )
{ 
  if (x = max)
      return x;

  else
      return (x + sum( x+1, max));      
}

int main()
{
  int min, max;

  printf("Enter your min value: ");
  scanf("%i", &min);

  printf("Enter your max number: ");
  scanf("%i", &max);

  printf("\n");

  printf(" %i\n %i\n", sum(min, max)); //calls the sum function and prints out the sum of the range of values

  return 0;     
}
```

As you can see on the bottom image rather than printing out the correct answer it only prints out the max value (7) along with an odd negative number.

My feeling is, is that i've called the sum function wrong in main on the last printf. I'm new to functions so i'm not really sure whats going on.

If anyone can help a novice that would be great.

Thanks, GR412.

[image: Output of program]

Comment: Recap "checking for equality". Line 5

Comment: If it gives the wrong output, what do you mean by "sort of works"?

Comment: @JohnColeman For a lot of folk, _'sort of works'_ means the compiler stopped crying. :\

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not sure if this a novice thing to say, but if something compiles for me it "sort of works" in my head. Of course it doesn't actually work. But it runs.

Comment: @tofro Oh yeah that was a silly mistake, it fixed the issue! However the negative number still persists.

Comment: The negative number is the result of undefined behavior. The final `printf` in your `main()` has a format string that expects 2 integer arguments, but you only supply 1 integer argument.

Comment: @IanAbbott Ahh yes another silly novice mistake, thanks that fixed the issue!

Comment: @tofro if you wish to put a proper answer i'll mark your answer as solved.

Comment: @GR412 Thanks - But that would just be a duplicate of a comment collector's. Let him have it. I sometimes think hinting someone to the bug is better help than providing a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int sum(int x, int max)
{
    if (x == max)
        return x;
    return max + sum(x, max - 1);
}
```

and your last print function sould be like this

```
printf(" %i\n", sum(min, max));
```

because your `sum` function returns only one value, but you told printf to print out two integers.

Answer (score -3):

The call:

```
sum(x+1,max);
```

is problematic, better to have:

```
x++;
sum(x,max);
```

Although I am not sure this is the cause of your error.

Comment: it isn't the cause of the error, and with pass by value I don't see why you deem it to be problematic

Comment: I see the problem : recursive functions need their own **auto** variables to store intermediate results if the calculation.

Comment: There is no problem to see. OP's function works fine as soon as the `=` vs. `==` typo is fixed. Since your answer had nothing to do with the actual problem and is hurting your rep, do you really want to keep it?